# Is there any way to sync between realm object database with mariadb?

Tags: mysql, .net, xamarin, realm

I want to use synchronization between mysql and realm database.is there any option or connector to achieve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option or connector, you would have to make one yourself.

I assume that you are trying to build your app so that it has offline capabilities. Daniel Causer is a master in constructing Offline capabilities to apps where he talks about just that, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MvIT-djcS0). He's also available on twitter and enjoys answering questions